# Search API group by issue with views

Tags: views, 8, search

I have a content type thats is called **course** which has a field that is a reference to a taxonomy called **category**.

My specification tells to build a search where users can search for the course title, category and other fields that the course type has. The search functions like intended and everything works great except the display view. Here is my setup:

- Drupal 8.5
- Search Api with DB / Solr Backend. (tried both)

So to come back: each course can have multiple categorys to be in which means that the view has to be grouped by the category. If I do that my view displays this:

**Category 1 Name**

- Course 1
- Course 2

**Category 1 Name, Category 2 Name**

- Course 3

**Category 2 Name**

- Course 4
- Course 5

**Category 3 Name, Category 2 Name**

- Course 6

**Category 3 Name**

- Course 7
- Course 8
- Course 9

As you can see courses that belong to multiple categorys are not listed underneath the respected category instead they are seperated by a comma. My goal is this:

**Category 1 Name**

- Course 1
- Course 2
- Course 3

**Category 2 Name**

- Course 3
- Course 4
- Course 5
- Course 6

**Category 3 Name**

- Course 6
- Course 7
- Course 8
- Course 9

such behaivor is easy to do if you dont use search api and want just to display a normal view. I have already read this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/2911939) but it seems my goal is not possible.

I'm asking now here if something has changed or if its possible to get this done with writing custom code? Maybe tell search api to return every result and display them with custom code grouped by the categorys? Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Can you post sql query of view?

Comment: @MrD how do I do that? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Group by your Category taxonomy and select to `Use rendered output to group rows`, then in your `Filter criteria` for your taxonomy turn on autocomplete of the category terms.</strike>

Add View

- View Settings: Show `Content` of type `Course` sorted by `Newest first`
- Page Settings: Create a page `selected`
- Page Display Settings: Display format `Unformatted list` of `fields`

note: you may not want to use the pager.

Edit new View

- Advanced:

  - Relationships: add `Relate nodes to taxonomy terms` with Vocabularies `{Taxonomy}` selected and `Require this relationship` selected
  - Use aggregation: Selected
- Fields: add `content: ID`, `Content: Title`, `Content: {Taxonomy}`

  - `Content: ID`: Exclude from display `selected`, Thousands marker: `-None-`
  - `Content: ID` Aggregation settings: Aggregation type: `Count DISTINCT`
  - `Content: Title`: Formatter `Plain text` and Link to the Content `selected`
  - `Content: {Taxonomy}`: Exclude from display `selected`
- Format:

  - Format settings: Grouping field Nr.1 `Content: {Taxonomy}` and Use rendered output to group rows `selected`
- Filter Criteria: add `Content: Title` and `Content: {taxonomy}`

  - `Content: Title`: Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it `selected` and Operator `Contains`
  - `Content: {Taxonomy}`: Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it `selected` and Operator `Is one of`
  - `Content: {Taxonomy}` settings: Vocabulary `{Taxonomy}` and Selection type `Autocomplete`
- Sort Criteria: `Content: {Taxonomy} (asc)`, `Content: Title (asc)`, `Content: Authored on (desc)`

Note: the preview will not display the Grouping titles, but this dose appear on the page.

Comment: I can't find the autocomplete part... can guide me?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking back to 7 on the autocomplete part, 8 dose that for you. You will need the Category to be among Fields and Format should be `Unformatted list` with the grouping set to the Category field, remember to select `Use rendered output to group rows`

Comment: did up a quick example on simplytest.me, select `Use aggregation` and adding the ID to the fields was the key. The example should be good for an hour or so. You will notice the views preview dose not display the grouping titles, but that does display on the actual page. user is admin, password is admin - https://dvx2.ply.st/courses

Comment: updated answer with a rundown of the view settings

Comment: this looks promising. I'm currently not at work to test it till monday.. but I got one more question. Does this work with facets?

Comment: I believe you should be able to use this with views layouts other then page, like `attachment`, `block`, etc. I would also think there is some permissions to do with search for the filters to work.

Comment: unfornately facets doesnt show this view as facet source. It seems it displays only search api sources.. is there any other way?